# Need to call layoutIfNeeded() when keyboard shows/disappears without all the subviews having their layoutIfNeeded() called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my view controller I currently have a `UITableView` and I animate the bottom constraint (this is pinned to the view controller's view) when the keyboard appears. However this is causing some UI glitches, I have stack views in the cells with subviews inside that can vary in width, when `layoutIfNeeded()` is called on the view controller's view it seems to all be calling in all the descendent views and causing the cells to move/change width. Is there a way to animate the table bottom constraint without this happening?

Comment: Try to use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Comment: Thanks but looking for a solution I can maintain myself and not to add more libraries.